# Новичку в длинной дискуссии предлагается перейти в чат, на что у него нет прав

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, чат, новые-участники

В [этой дискуссии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432724/178576) участник (с текущей «репутацией» 13) [пожаловался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432550/#comment448431_432724), что движок предлагает ему перейти в чат, но прав на это у него пока недостаточно ([нужно 20](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)).

Я считаю, что следует либо понизить «порог входа» в чат, либо не предлагать участнику с «репутацией» ниже двадцати воспользоваться чатом (в длинной дискуссии).

Comment: У меня дополнительный вопрос к данному: ресурс ограничен в серверном месте или почему так не приветствуются длинные дискуссии?

Comment: задайте, пожалуйста, по этому поводу вопрос кнопкой в правом верхнем углу.

Comment: Хмы... ладно... могу конечно и задать... просто увидел связанным с этим вопрос и решил заодно спросить... разве он здесь мешает или не по теме?

Comment: @Arik, у комментария значительно меньше шансов быть замеченным, нежели у вопроса.

Comment: Ага... выдаёт ошибку - «Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества проекта...» … и иди знай что в нём не так :(

Comment: [Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества проекта](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/276/178576)

Comment: у меня гипотеза по поводу парсера: возможно, он игнорирует кириллицу. попробуйте добавить латинских букв, цифр и прочих не-кириллических символов.

Comment: Хе :) а ларчик просто открывался — сделал несколько раз копи-пэйст текста и вопрос прошёл валидацию, а затем выбрал правку и удалил всё дубликаты.

Comment: Возможно, стоит пускать в чат «приглашённого» пользователя независимо от его репутации. (Но только в _этот_ чат, в остальные — по правилам.)

Comment: @Arik SO - не место для дискуссий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обсудил с ребятами. Это не ошибка, так задумано по умолчанию. Данная проблема обсуждалось уже несколько раз на Stack Overflow на английском. Идея заключалась в разрешении модераторам назначать права на участие в чате по запросу. Результат все тот же - решили оставить текущую реализацию.

---

Постараюсь поднять дискуссию в команде еще раз, чтобы понять почему именно было принято данное решение.

Comment: можно ведь хотя бы **не предлагать** возможность, на которую нет прав.

Comment: Мне кажется, для чатов по вопросу имеет смысл автоматические давать разрешение всем участникам вопроса, вне зависимости от репутации. (Кроме тех, кто в бане.)

Comment: (Я имею в виду чаты, которые автоматически создаются из комментариев.)

Answer (score 3):

Вроде бы нашел обходное решение.

1. **Создайте новый чат вручную.**
   (Вообще, подходит любой, в котором вы являетесь владельцем (статус `owner`). Проще всего создать новый чат. В чате, который создается по предложению от системы, владельца нет. Такой чат не подойдет для этого решения).
2. **В чате нажмите на кнопку `room▼` и выберите вариант `control access`.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. **Явным образом выдайте пользователю права на общение в чате.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: по поводу ответа. Я тут перечитал ответ Nicolas в четвертый раз. Так он об этой возможности и говорил? Я думал, имеются в виду модераторы сайта, а не модераторы чата.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: ну вот в свой чат можно пригласить пользователя с 1 репы и дать ему права

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: ага, я удалил там сообщения, не должно быть оповещений. Тоже заметил эту штуку. Иногда хотелось бы, чтобы все-таки оставались оповещения.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: возможно, дело в этом. Или он просто обнаруживает и блокирует попытки изучать его )

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27168/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-alexander-barakin).