# Не переведено сообщение о невозможности воспользоваться чатом

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, нет-в-transifex, новые-участники, чат

Связанная тема: [Новичку в длинной дискуссии предлагается перейти в чат, на что у него нет прав](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/591/178576)

---

При достаточно длинной дискуссии участникам выдаётся предложение продолжить обсуждение в чате.

Если участник ещё не набрал [20 баллов репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat), при нажатии на предлагаемую ссылку ему выдаётся сообщение о недоступности чата.

Проблема в том, что сообщение не переведено на русский — «*имярек* has only *баллов* reputation. [not yet enough](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) to chat»:

[image: сообщение о невозможности воспользоваться чатом]

Помимо этого, ссылка в сообщении ведёт на [англоязычный faq](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq). Возможно, имеет смысл заменить её хотя бы на [эту ссылку из справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) (более подходящей темы в справке не нашёл).

Comment: [FAQ есть](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/983/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BE-stack-exchange), но лучше ссылку на привилегию.

Comment: Сейчас, насколько я вижу, участнику явным образом выдается разрешение на запись в чате. Но это если я создаю чат. У вас там остался второй аккаунт, чтобы проверить?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/485790/188698