# Можно ли произвольно создать чат-комнату на основе комментариев?

Tags: поддержка, чат

При достижении определенного количества комментариев система предлагает создать чат. Можно ли воспользоваться этим функционалом для создания комнаты по своему усмотрению, т.е. до предложения системы или же необходимо поступать так:

Создаем чат в общем списке через ["create new room"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new), создаем комнату, получаем ссылку на неё и публикуем комментарием к вопросу/ответу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создать новую чистую комнату и пригласить в неё кого угодно можно в любой момент. Но скопировать комментарии из вопроса или ответа можно только двумя способами:

1. Если система предложила перейти в чат
2. Если модератор инициировал перенос

Насколько я знаю, произвольно создать чат на основе комментариев нельзя.

Общение в чате несколько свободнее, чем в комментариях, но у него есть свои недостатки по сравнению с комментариями:

- Комментарии находятся прямо под сообщением и их видно сразу, а чат нужно открывать.
- Чат недоступен для участников со слишком низкой репутацией (даже если создан на основе комментариев, что досадно, [уже обсуждалось](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/591/181472) и является [статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be)).
- В комментариях всегда можно ответить одному из участников (например, через год вы нашли решение получше), а чат закроется через пару недель неактивности.

В общем и целом я рекомендую поступать следующим образом:

- Если вы уточняете подробности по вопросу или ответу — делайте это в комментариях. Эти подробности будут нужны всем будущим читателям.

  - Все полученные уточнения желательно перенести в само сообщение — там им самое место.
  - Все устаревшие комментарии желательно удалять, чтобы не создавать шум.
- Если вы просто хотите обсудить какую-то тему или переходите в режим техподдержки, то есть по шагам ведёте другого участника к решению — создавайте чат.

Comment: на мой взгляд было бы удобнее иметь возможность создать чат прямо из вопроса, т.е. кнопка создать чат в группе кнопок поделиться править закрыть тревога, как Вы считаете такое возможно?! либо же пишем *коменты* пока система не скажет *ай - ай -ай* может стоит инициировать вопрос-опросник по данному функционалу?!

Comment: @Bald56rus: ответил вам в обновлении ответа.