# Добавить способ создать чат под вопросом/ответом без совета от системы

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, чат, шаблонные-комментарии

### Контекст

Многие из нас, кто вёл сколько-нибудь существенные беседы в комментариях, сталкивался с *предложением от системы **продолжить разговор в чате***, когда беседа становится достаточно длинной.

Как правило, это означает, что в комментариях ожидается крупный диалог в *режиме техподдержки*<sup>*</sup>, который будущим читателям вряд ли будет интересен. Существенные детали можно (и нужно!) вынести прямо в вопрос, а до их выяснения вести диалог в более интерактивном режиме, что в таких случаях быстрее приведёт к продуктивным изменениям.

### Проблема

Странно то, что сделать это *одним щелчком* можно исключительно тогда, когда это предлагает система. Мы знаем **обходной путь**: создать чат-комнату самостоятельно, пригласить туда автора, закинуть ссылку на предмет обсуждения. Но это **намного дольше**, настолько, что делать это зачастую нет желания и вопрос остаётся висеть.

### Решение

Добавить способ инициировать подобную беседу вручную, не дожидаясь совета от системы. В идеале, эффект должен быть таким же, как от щелчка по ссылке в подсказке:

- оставление автокомментария **"Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате"**
- новая комната со скопированными комментариями и ссылкой на обсуждаемый пост

Инициировать такой процесс можно кнопкой <kbd>продолжить в чате</kbd> (или аналогичная формулировка) где-то недалеко от формы комментария, обязательно с окном подтверждения. Поскольку для создания чат-комнат есть [порог репутации (100)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), эта кнопка должна быть доступна только перешагнувшим этот порог.

Поскольку для участия в чате тоже есть определённый порог репутации, если у автора поста её недостаточно, кнопка должна быть скрыта.

#### Плюсы

- Модераторам придётся реже пользоваться переносом комментариев в чат, потому что условия возникновения совета **не идеальны**.
- Вопрос/ответ будет быстрее доведён до состояния, нужного ТСу, если кто-то готов этим заниматься.

#### Минусы

- Человеческий фактор. Чаты будут создавать и тогда, когда они не очень-то нужны, ведь порог репутации для создания новых чатов (100) крайне невысок.

#### Особенности (непонятно, плюсы или минусы)

- Вопросы **не по теме** сообщества могут получить в чатах *вторую жизнь*.

---

#### См. также:

- [Можно ли произвольно создать чат-комнату на основе комментариев?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1824/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2)

<sub>* ([Nick Volynkin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin), по CC-BY-SA)</sub>

Comment: Примерно тот же вопрос на англоязычной мете. [Create a chat room that has history from an existing solution](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318286/2790048)

Answer (score 5):

Скорее всего, данная особенность не будет добавлена.

Главная часть проекта – сайт вопросов и ответов. Именно он представляет  ценность для большинства разработчиков. Цель проекта – создать свободную базу знаний. Знания создаются нами, сообществом. Чтобы мы могли самоорганизоваться и непрерывно улучшать систему (движок) у нас есть Мета  На Мете мы обсуждаем правила и нововведения. Мета, в основном, интересна активной части сообщества, тем, кто вовлечен в создание знаний. Чаты – это «[третье место](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/)». Они нужны для всего, что нельзя разместить ни на основном сайте, ни на Мете ([пара слов о правилах чатов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139382/274323)). Все что публикуется в чатах, публикуется исключительно для тех людей, непосредственно общающихся в них в данный момент.

Что будет, если появится возможность избежать формального процесса создания вопроса? – Короткий заголовок, и чат с желающим помочь. В таком случае, проект потеряет свою основную ценность в глаза разработчиков: в чатах нет возможности структурировать информацию, практически нет систематики общения, а вся информация теряется в тумане ненужной информации.

Соглашусь, было бы здорово сначала уточнить вопрос, чтобы можно было опубликовать полезный ответ. Для этого уже есть комментарии.

На сколько я могу видеть, три основных причины простыней из комментариев:

1. Недостаточно информации в исходном сообщении. Автор уточняет исходное сообщение в комментариях.
2. Разбираются дополнительные вопросы. Получив нужный ответ, автор, невзначай, задает еще несколько в комментариях.
3. Дополнение к ответу от другого знатока, который согласен с ответом в общем, но предлагает изменить детали.

Возможные решения для них.

1. Вносить уточнения в тело исходного сообщения. Если автор не может толком сформулировать вопрос, попробовать задать уточняющие вопросы в комментариях.
2. Задавать новый вопрос, при необходимости, дополняя его ссылкой на текущий.
3. Публикация альтернативного ответа, даже если он в общих чертах повторяет уже имеющийся и дальнейший разбор нюансов в чате, с публикацией результатов на основной сайт.

Таким образом, на мой взгляд, чат, как инструмент создания основной ценности, нужен не так часто. Используют его в большинстве случаев знатоки в случае реальной необходимости.

Конечно же, чаты полезны. Они вносят дополнительную «живую» составляющую в академический формат Stack Overflow. Необходимость возможность создания чата к любому вопросу – дело очень спорное, и, на мой взгляд, идущая в разрез с идеологией проекта.

Comment: Целью предложения является избежание вмешательства модераторов с целью ликвидации "расширенных дискуссий" в комментариях ещё **до** того, как дискуссия уже разгорелась и до ссылки на чат не придётся откручивать комментарии слишком далеко. Ответ понятен, но он не предлагает способов эту проблему решить существующими средствами. Возможно, я недостаточно хорошо обозначил цель в тексте предложения.

Comment: А **проблема злоупотребления чатами** достаточно неплохо решается ограничением доступа к этой возможности по общему уровню репутации или рейтингу по меткам вопроса (бронзовый значок по метке?). Лимит есть уже сейчас, 100 общей репутации, и он должен отсечь как минимум большую часть оффтопика. Возможно, стоит поднять планку для создания комнат "прямо из вопросов". Ведь если уж очень надо, даже при 100 репутации можно сходить и сделать комнату вручную.

Comment: Чтобы прояснить вопрос, подскажите, какие вы видите основные способы применения данной функциональной особенности? Возможно я что-то упустил из виду.

Comment: Например, когда "Недостаточно информации в исходном сообщении" и нельзя сформулировать несколько точных вопросов, по которым автор может уточнить формулировку. Либо вопросы сформулировать можно, но автор не в состоянии на них ответить. В результате это неизбежно вырастает в цепочку вопросов, из которых становится понятно, что автор может предоставить, но "the damage is done", дискуссия уже вовсю идёт.

Comment: @D-side [В вашем ответе выше](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2687/6), хорошо описаны главные причины против подобного использования. Позволю себе повториться, чтобы их подчеркнуть. 1) Отвечающие – разработчики, по большей части, высокой квалификации. Им есть чем заняться помимо чатов с отдельными участниками. Отвечая на вопрос, они помогают сотням (или даже тысячам) коллег, при этом нет привязки ко времени (в случае с чатом, надо отвечать здесь и сейчас). 2) В идеальном мире, задаются только качественные вопросы. Комментарии – это уже послабление.

Comment: Добавлю, что во времена до эры Stack Exchange, у нас не просто не было чатов, у нас были ограничения в 4 комментария от одного участника к одному сообщению. Что, в нашем представлении, вполне соответствует формату вопрос–ответ.

Comment: Проблема всё равно остаётся, но очень сильно зажата: только под вопросами и только на достаточно узкие темы, по которым "база знаний" пока посредственная и даже часто возникающие проблемы не освещены. И это будет слишком прямым и рискованным решением. Мы можем жить с этой проблемой, но стоит признавать её существование и искать решение. Возможно, для этого стоит сделать отдельный вопрос, надо подумать.

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я понимаю, чат сейчас не может быть связан с вопросом, т.е. нет возможности переносить в него и обратно комментарии из чата, это все сейчас делается, по сути, вручную (часть сообщений из Q&A копируется в чат, и потом уже - удаляется авторами или модераторами из Q&A, при необходимости). Т.е. чат сейчас - это отдельный сервис.

И да, процедура инициации дискуссии слишком дорога, чтобы ей пользоваться. Думаю, плюсы в ней очевидны: если дискуссия будет начинаться в чате, то будет больше шансов соблюдать правила SO в Q&A.

Конечно, это поставит все с ног на голову: придется в вопросы/комментарии вытаскивать умные мысли, а не наоборот - прятать дискуссии в чате. Но сейчас и последним-то мало кто занимается, ну разве что модераторы и фанаты. Думаю, если плотнее интегрировать чат в Q&A, то плюсов будет больше, т.е. люди будут к QA относиться как к **чистовику**, а к чату - как к **черновику**. Но скорее всего, это потребует какого-то времени на обкатку системы и есть вероятность того, что роли чистовика-черновика вполне могут поменяться местами на какое-то время (вернее даже - просто, "чистовик" может на какое-то время лишиться той активности, которой обладает сейчас).

Согласен с @Nicolas, такая возможность обнажит проблемные места ruSO: добыча качественного контента перейдет в ручной режим, т.е. придется напрягать состав модераторов, чтобы обогащать Q&A. Сейчас ведь этим занимаются сами участники, т.е. наполнение базы идет самотеком.

Простыми словами: бюрократия SO не позволит нам пользоваться удобными инструментами, не учитывая последствий для SO, к которым это приведет.

Answer (score -2):

<sub>Общий ответ для голосования **против** и аргументов к этому: добавляйте свои доводы!</sub>

---

## *Это не нужно.*

### Под вопросами

Ситуация, при которой для приведения вопроса в порядок необходим чат, не говорит о вопросе ничего хорошего. Если вопрос выглядит показательным примером, то для его "шлифовки" можно приложить дополнительные усилия (есть **мотив**):

- вручную создать комнату
- пригласить туда автора
- приложить ссылку

Если лень всё же одерживает верх — возможно, **вопрос** просто **не стоит того** и **лучше пройти мимо**?

Ведь если мы дадим возможность создавать чат где угодно, то **не всем** (возможность предполагает *ответственность*). Есть причины сделать порог **очень высоким**, чтобы чаты создавались только когда они действительно нужны. *Но тогда эта возможность будет доступна очень немногим, кроме модераторов, у кого она и без того есть.* В чём смысл?

Сделав возможность перехода дискуссии под вопросами в чат **одним кликом**, мы неявно выразим мысль, что **"у нас это обычное дело"**, но мы не хотим создавать такого впечатления.

**Вопросы, создающие подобные ситуации, заслуживают закрытия или просто игнорирования.**

### О чатах под ответами

В вопросах ведь дело обстоит совсем иначе: вопрос, большая часть которого закопана в комментариях, просто не успеет заинтересовать отвечающих.

Под ответами вмешательство требуется куда реже. У прохожих есть мотив читать дискуссии под ответами: ведь там могут быть ценные детали о решении. **Хотя даже такие дискуссии нежелательны, порог возникновения предложения** о переходе в чат для ответов **достаточно низок** и существующая система там вполне справляется.