# Слить вопрос в чат

Tags: предложение

Предлагаю добавить такую опцию, и чтобы за нее можно было голосовать на том же уровне, что и за закрытие вопроса (т.е. любой желающий с необходимым минимумом привилегий).

Предполагается использовать опцию для вопросов, которые не доросли до формата SO.

Примеры:

1. [C++ Антивирусник не дает скачивать файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714770/c-%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B)
2. [Синхронизация mutex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729102/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-mutex)

Таких можно много найти. Добавляйте в комментариях еще примеры, кто понимает о чем речь.

Предполагаю, что это будет удаление вопроса со всеми ответами и комментариями и создание комнаты с заголовком вопроса и точной копии в нее всех сообщений, которые до этого были в вопросе.

Возможно предложение уже было на общей мете, кто найдет, просьба приложить ссылку.

Comment: таки если с автором хотите в чате пообщаться и он согласен и нужны все комментарии в этом чате, то можно тревогу модератору на вопросе поставить например, чтоб он создал..обычно из-под вопроса комментарии сразу попадают в тот самый чат. а вот постов красиво написано "Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии и перемещены в чат такой-то"

Comment: Что-то я [сильно сомневаюсь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2656/181100), что это произойдёт.

Comment: Тут два действия в одном: 1) перенести вопрос и комментарии в чат 2) удалить вопрос с комментариями. Первое уже реализовано. Второе — удаление вопроса — тоже возможно через голосование за удаление. А всё вместе и одним движением — имхо, слишком.

Comment: А по-моему, вполне нормальный вопрос. Не знаю, чем он тебе не угодил.

Comment: @Qwertiy, тут дискуссия, в ходе которой ТС потерял интерес к банальному решению. Есть вопросы, которые плавно перетекают в другое русло - дискуссионные вопросы, в основном - без ответов.

Comment: Возможно, мой пример не так красноречив. Просто, иногда вижу вопросы, которые логичнее смотрелись бы в чате.

Comment: [в Stack Overflow подкасте (#115)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/18/podcast-115-stack-overflow-reads-mean-tweets/) во второй половине обсуждается менторство для первых вопросов, чтобы более приятное (доброжелательное) первое впечатление было без снижения качества вопросов (я так понял, пилотная программа уже есть. Вопрос как это масштабировать).

Comment: related: [Mentorship Research Project - Results + Wrap-Up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357198/4279)

Comment: Да, @jfs, это отличный вариант. Вот именно так я и представлял изначально чат на SO (черновик/чистовик - как раз эта тема), т.е. когда вопросы рождаются из чата, а не наоборот. Тогда вопросы будут проходить минимальный "кастинг", и только весомые - уходить в Q&A. Когда у нас этот проект тоже запустится? И, кстати, неплохо было бы получить перевод этой ветки.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите помочь автору улучшить вопрос, то вы уже можете оставить комментарий, сами внести правку, проголосовать за закрытие по подходящей причине. Без перехода в чат.

Если комментарии слишком активные будут, система сама предложит чат создать и вы можете в чат перейти, если есть желание.

То есть, если вы хотите продолжать говорить, то просто продолжайте говорить, без необходимости нажимать кнопку "создать чат".

Если вы хотите удалить вопрос, который пока ещё "не дорос", то голосуйте за закрытие и система сама может его удалить позже при отсутствии правок или явно можно за удаление голосовать. См. [Как работает удаление? Что может стать причиной удаления сообщения и что представляет собой процесс удаления? Каковы критерии для удаления?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/23044)

Вопросы с голосами за закрытие  и часть других требующих внимания  сообщений автоматически в [очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review) попадают, где опытные участники могут улучшить сайт, выбрав предложенные действия. Если вы уже прочли  вопрос и знаете какое действие предпринять (комментарий, правка, минус, голосование за закрытие), то просто выполните это действие, без  предварительного перемещения вопроса в очередь проверок. Если сомневаетесь, что делать, то (для будущих ссылок) опубликуйте обсуждение на Мете.

Некоторые участники группировались в отдельном чате, чтобы организовано голосовать за закрытие, но это пытается обойти ограничение, что каждый участник имеет один голос: *каждый сам должен решать голосовать за закрытие или нет.*

У меня самого идея чистилища, для вопросов с ещё нерешённой судьбой, возникала (более интерактивная версия очереди проверок, с участием авторов самих вопросов). Но на стадии идей по практической реализации находил, что этот процесс плохо вписывался с другими инструментами на сайте — не улучшал ситуацию практически. То есть разделять "черновик" и "чистовик" не выгодно на Stack Overflow.

Не ясно что можно достигнуть явной кнопкой "слить в чат", что существующая функциональность уже лучше не делает.