# Обсуждение вопроса в чате

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Пытаюсь продолжить обсуждение вопроса в чате, но получаю такое сообщение

> You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here.

Репутация у меня больше 20 но писать в чате я не могу. Почему?

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58507/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-user

Comment: попробуй обновить страницу в чата. Добавь ссылку на сам чат в вопрос

Comment: @Grundy Обновил страницу в чате. Ничего не изменилось. Ссылку на чат добавил в вопрос.

Comment: А ты зарегистрированный?

Comment: @Qwertiy, как минимум пометки о незарегистрированности нету :-) Хотя, возможно, не зарегистрирован в чатах!

Comment: @Grundy, если бы была, я бы предложил зарегистрироваться :)

Comment: @Grundy, похоже, [хак](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3433/178988) не работает ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, работает, но автора вопроса _нет_ в указанной им комнате

Comment: Теперь все работает.

Comment: @user, как ты проверил?

Comment: @Grundy Отправил сообщение.

Comment: @user, а теперь - это когда?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Теперь - это 11 минут назад. Я смог написать в чат 11 минут назад.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Новичку в длинной дискуссии предлагается перейти в чат, на что у него нет прав](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/591/%d0%9d%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2)